# How can I replace selected customTableCellA with customTableCellB

Tags: ios, uitableview

How can I replace selected customTableCellA with customTableCellB

- I already have a table view working with customTableCellAs
- I want to replace customTableCellA with customTableCellB when it is selected.
- customTableCellB is 50 pixels taller than customTableCellA

How can I implement this properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Create an `@property` array `NSMutableArray *selectedIndexPathArray` and instantiate it in `viewDidLoad`, then

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat cellHeight = //customTableCellA height
    if ([self.selectedIndexPathArray containsObject:indexPath]) {
         cellHeight = //customTableCellB height
    } else {
         cellHeight = //customTableCellA height
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    if ([self.selectedIndexPathArray containsObject:indexPath]) {
         //Load customTableCellB
    } else {
         //Load customTableCellA
    }
    //Other code
    ...
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self.selectedIndexPathArray containsObject:indexPath]) {
         //If you want to remove the selection in second touch, do
         //[self.selectedIndexPathArray removeObject:indexPath];
    } else {
         [self.selectedIndexPathArray addObject:indexPath];
    }
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNonne]; 
    //Select appropriate UITableViewRowAnimation
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```